# Node mocha test case is not running

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run the following code with node.

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

 client
.init()
.url('http://www.webdriveruniversity.com/')
.click('#login-portal')
.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log('Title is: ' + title);
})
.end();
```

I am getting this error

```
DEBUG wdio-config: @wdio/sync not found, runn
ing tests asynchronous
C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\webdriverFramework\loginPortalTest.js:6
.init()
 ^

TypeError: client.init is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\webdriverFramework\l
oginPortalTest.js:6:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:7
00:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

How can I resolve this? Previously I had the issue with version. But I upgraded to new version.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you lack [@wdio/sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wdio/sync) and your runner toggles into asynchronous mode. So `webdriverio.remote(options)` returns promise that has not `.init()` method.